# Meteor Minimongo insert documents returned from Method leads to Error on subscriptions

Tags: meteor, minimongo

Consider a collection created for server and client:

```js
export const MyCollection = new Mongo.Collection('myCollection')
```

I receive Documents from the Server due to performance reasons via Methods:

*server*

```js
Meteor.methods({
  getDocs() {
    return MyCollection.find({ ... }).fetch()
  }
})
```

On the client I store them inside the local-collection:

*client*

```js
const LocalCollection = MyCollection._collection
Meteor.call('getDocs', { ... }, (err, docs) => {
  docs.forEach(doc => LocalCollection.insert(doc))
})
```

Now this works fine but when I run a subscription at another point that also returns documents, that were among those, returned by the method, I receive the following error:

> Uncaught Error: Expected not to find a document already present for an add

My question is, whether to flush the Localcollection before the subscription manually or if there is a way to just tell it to "override the existing docs, no matter what"?

Note, that I am using the `LocalCollection` on the client because `allow/deny` is by default set to deny on everything and any documents that are inserted like so

```js
Meteor.call('getDocs', { ... }, (err, docs) => {
  docs.forEach(doc => MyCollection.insert(doc))
})
```

would be rejected to be inserted.

Comment: I have the same problem. I try to make a persist cache. Have you got found any solution ?